# Question on proof that meromorphic functions are the rational functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I have a question regarding Meromorphic functions from the second line of the following proof. Why does a small neighborhood $|z|<\epsilon$ with no other pole the same as saying $F$ has no finite pole in $|z|>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$?

> Theorem 0.2. The only meromorphic functions on $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ are rational functions.
> Proof. Let $F: \hat{\mathbb{C}} \rightarrow \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ be a meromorphic function.
> Claim-1. $F$ has only finitely many poles $\left\{p_{1}, \cdots, p_{n}\right\}$ in the complex plane C.
>
> To see this, note that $F(1 / z)$ has either a pole or zero at $z=0$. In either case there is a small neighborhood $|z|<\varepsilon$ which has no other pole. Which is the same as saying that $F$ has no finite pole in $|z|>1 / \varepsilon$. But $|z| \leq 1 / \varepsilon$ is compact, and since all poles are isolated, this shows that there are only finitely many poles. Now, corresponding to each of the poles $p_{k} \in \mathbb{C}$ there exists a polynomial $Q_{k}$ (see Remark $0.2$ in Lecture-20) such that
> $$
> F(z)=Q_{k}\left(\frac{1}{z-p_{k}}\right)+H_{k}(z)
> $$
> where $G_{k}$ is holomorphic on a whole neighborhood around $p_{k}$ (including at the point $p_{k}$ ). Similarly if $|z|>R$, we can write
> $$
> F(z)=Q_{\infty}(z)+H_{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)
> $$
> where as before, $H_{\infty}(z)$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z=0$.

(note that I have only included the first half of the proof. The rest can be found [here](http://math.iisc.ac.in/%7Evvdatar/courses/2020_Jan/Lecture_Notes/Lecture-16.pdf))

Comment: It's that $F(1/z)$ having no poles in $\vert z\vert < \epsilon$ is the same as $F(z)$ having no poles in $\vert z\vert > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ except possibly at $z=\infty$ (which is $z=0$ for $F(1/z)$)

Comment: @podiki Thank you again for your super fast and clear response--you answered my last Rudin question too yesterday.